# Why does git / SourceTree wants me to edit conflicts in the source rather than in the destination of a merge?

Tags: git, merge, atlassian-sourcetree, git-pull

We are using git via SourceTree. I am in the process of merging a master (which has previously been updated because of some hotfixes) into a release branch (which was broken out of the master a couple of months back).

Source Tree is indicating that there are conflicts when doing a Pull Request from master -->release and advises me to use the commands below (via the atlassian-Stash-GUI).

However what I don’t understand is this: I appear to be solving the conflicts then via the commands below in the master and pushing them into the master. I also end up having the changes from NextRelease then in the master when I'd rather expected to have them only in NextRelease because of this Pull Request.

I would have thought that I should end up via these commands in the NextRelease branch and solve the conflicts there and leave my master unchanged.

Am I doing something wrong here?

```
git fetch origin release/NextRelease

git checkout master
git merge FETCH_HEAD

<now we should resolve the conflicts>

git commit
git push origin HEAD
```

Comment: We also use git via SourceTree and Stash and I have found the directions in Stash for merge conflicts to be backwards to the way we operate (and you seem to want). Flipping the release branch and master in the instructions has worked fine for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how a pull request works. You resolve conflicts in the source the merge happens.  Pull requests are most commonly used for code review.

As an alternate, you can just do normal merge and the conflict resolution should take place on the source.

```
git checkout release/NextRelease

git merge master

<Resolve conflicts. Make sure everything looks good>

git push origin release/NextRelease
```

Comment: Do you know why a pull request works this way, e.g. making me edit the conflicts in the source branch rather than in the destination branch?

Comment: I think it's easiest to view a pull request as "The changes that you are looking at right here is what is going to apply to the destination branch."

Not "these changes are going onto the destination branch plus some conflict resolution changes that aren't included here".

It's a way to be 100% confident on what is going to the destination.